# Sonos Cloud API: audioClip synchronised playing in group

Tags: api, cloud, sonos, audioclip

Will it be possible in the future to be able to play a audioClip for a whole group?

Now one should iterate all players manually, by which the triggered audioClip is not being played in sync.
Is it planned to be added to the *groups* (or even the *households*) API as well?

https://developer.sonos.com/reference/control-api/audioclip/loadaudioclip/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your interest in the platform. We're excited to see what our developers are building. We can't comment on future plans, but we'll take your suggestion back to the dev team. We can share that we're adding the ability to play audio clips on bonded players. Keep an eye on the [Sonos developer portal blog](https://developer.sonos.com/blog/) for updates.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I look forward to the elaborated use. If bonded players will be supported, I guess group support should be feasible too...

Comment: Hi @yrg : any update on a ETA for the API update? It has been a year almost since last update...

Comment: Hi @Bartel. I no longer work at Sonos. I suggest you contact customer service as they should be able to help. Good luck!

Comment: Any chance of allowing audio clips on the local (non cloud) API?